# Are there any drawbacks to using comments as a child post type?

Tags: comments, children, development-strategy

I am planning on making a website for users to post help requests for companies to bet on. So I will have a post type "help request" and thought of using comments for storing the price offer and a few other data fields from companies.

One of the benefits is that I already have a connection between requests and offers. Plus also thinking about optimization I would put more strain on the wp_comments table rather than wp_posts table. I think that also is somewhat of a benefit.

But what am I missing? Conflicts with using comments for different purposes also (company reviews)? I could also see that wp_comments query and functions could lack some of the things wp_query would offer.

Has anyone done something like this and run into problems? And do you think the benefits are even worth considering?

Comment: this sounds less like a question and more like a discussion, which isn't the format of this site. You need to be able to mark an answer as not just "best" but as factually correct, can you edit your question to clearly state a single specific question? If you're just looking for anecdotes/reassurance or an open ended discussion of best practices you might be best asking in a discussion forum instead